# Android Studio: Android Theme.AppCompat error

Tags: java, android, xml, android-theme, android-studio-2.1

I'm following Google's [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) on Android app development using Android Studio (I'm using 2.1.3), and I'm following the instructions, however, I have been unable to run my basic app without it crashing immediately. Android Studio's Android Monitor outputs the following:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myfirstapp, PID: 2384
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

What am I doing wrong? What theme should I use, and what code should I edit? For the record, I am outputting to a Nexus 5 both physically and emulator, and to Android API 23.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity

Comment: Can you post the `themes.xml` where you define your theme?  It's in `res/values/themes.xml` and should look something like `<style name="Theme.myApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`(along with any customizations to the parent theme you'd like.  Some people use `styles.xml` instead of `themes.xml`, but same thing.)  Assuming you're using an `AppCompatActivity`, you need to make sure you associate that theme with MainActivity in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file-- add `android:theme="@style/Theme.myApp"`within the `<Activity>` (and/or `<Application>`) tags..
`

Comment: My `styles.xml` is as follows
`<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
`

Comment: Try to change the theme of the activity such as HoloDark or HoloLight etc. I have also faced the same problem, but after changing the theme, the error didnot revoke.

Answer (score 0):

In your Manifest, below permissions, inside activity tag, put/change attribute `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"`

Or if you want to customize your theme change it to `android:theme="@style/MyTheme"`
And add new resource file inside res/values and name it "styles" (styles.xml) and use it as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    // customize your theme here...(optional)
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: I edited my `AndroidManifest.xml` to include `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` in the `<application>` tag but that didn't work. Where should I put `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"`?

Comment: Brother, your manifest must have a theme already, you just need to spot it. You do not have to add it. You need to change it.

Comment: The theme is there, I did replace it with `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"`, and I still get the error readout
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

Comment: Try second method using styles file. File name styles contains s while in code its style only.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the package name at the top the MainActivity.java to resemble the root directory of your app.

That said, the next this you will have to do is add the following import statement to thesame file.

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

Then you rebuild and run the app again.